# Use asyncio objects with ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I am new to the asyncio and concurrent.futures. I am trying to understand a complex code which uses asyncio queues with concurrent.futures. I was able to reproduce the error in a simple and minimal example. The error I am receiving is `TypeError: cannot pickle '_queue.SimpleQueue' object`
The problem currently I am facing is when I am trying to pass asyncio queue objects in ProcessPoolExecutor.

I am not able to understand how the combination of Processpoolexecutor and asyncio work under the hood. Specifically,

- I am trying to understand if I can use/pass asyncio queues to multiprocessing.
- Is this issue related to multiprocessing and asyncio or the way I am using zip function and is related to pickling.

Below is the code snippet to reproduce the error.

```
import os
import asyncio
import traceback
import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor


def runner(coro_fn, *args):
    loop1 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        print(f"PID FN: {os.getpid()}")
        coro = coro_fn(*args)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop1)
        ret = loop1.run_until_complete(coro)
        return ret
    finally:
        loop1.close()


async def run_add(nums):
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(add(nums[0]))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(add(nums[1]))
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


async def add(num: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    print(f"num: {num}, pid: {os.getpid()}, tm: {datetime.datetime.now()}")


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.max_queue_size = 24

    async def initialize(self):

        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            val1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            val2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
            val3 = [asyncio.Queue(5)]  # Dummy part to reproduce error.
            val4 = [asyncio.Queue(5)]  # Dummy part to reproduce error.
            executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
            # tasks = [executor.submit(run_fn, run_add, (i, j)) for i, j in zip(val1, val2)] # works
            # tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, runner, run_add, (i, j)) for i, j in zip(val1, val2)] # works
            tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, runner, run_add, (i, j)) for i, j in
                     zip(val3, val4)]  # Throws error
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        except Exception as _ex:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            raise _ex


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_object = TestClass()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_default_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32))
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(test_object.initialize())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        raise ex
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Comment: before checking your code in detail, as a thumb rule: asyncio queues are good to pass data across different tasks inside the same asyncio loop (one loop, tied to a thread, tied to a process). And Pickle-related errors have to do with objects that have to be passed as parameters to sub-processes. For multiprocessing stuff, one has to use "multiprocessing.Queue"

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not reproduce the error as is -
but keep in mind that the way to pass objects back and forth across processes iswith `multiprocessing.Queue`

`asyncio.Queue` is good only for passing objects across tasks running in the same asyncio loop (in the same thread, same process) - the only thing it does is that the calls that would be blocking in the "normal" `queue.Queue()` and `multiprocessing.Queue()` instead yield the would-be-blocking wait to the asyncio loop, which will step through other tasks (which will eventually post/read to the queue)

Just write your code to use the `.get_nowait` and `.put_nowait`  calls and you are good to use the other queue variants in async code. (Or, otherwise, if you want blocking code, you will have to create a ThreadPoolExecutor and make `put` and `get` queue methods wait in other threads - that is a layer of complexity that you don't need)